# ListView in RemoteViews

Tags: android

I need to add a ListView to a RemoteView (used in a custom notification, not a widget).

My problem is once I add the ListView (or for that matter, any view) I can't access it to add Items into it.

If I try to workaround it by providing a custom list wich initializes it's items using static helpers, I get runtime exception saying that the custom view class cannot be found.

What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> I need to add a ListView to a RemoteView (used in a custom notification, not a widget).

That is not possible, for two reasons.

First, you cannot put a `ListView` in a `RemoteViews` except on Honeycomb and higher.

Second, you cannot receive user input from a `Notification`'s `RemoteViews` (e.g., you cannot use a `Button` in a `Notification`, even though you can in an app widget).

> What is the proper way to do this?

Use a simple `Notification`, where when the user taps on it, a `PendingIntent` pointing to an activity of yours is invoked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. In many apps - especially media players but also dialers, a mini control panel which includes buttons is added to the background notifications panel, so there is probably a way to do that atleast...

Comment: @Oren: You are mistaken. It *may* work on some devices, and will work if the "notification" is really part of the home screen. You cannot reliably have interactive widgets (e.g., `Button`) on `Notification` custom views.

Comment: @CommonsWare the Widgetsoid-app is able to put a customizable energycontrol-like widget as an interactive notification into the notification-panel. It provides buttons with status-lights to toggle device-features like sensors, bluetooth, or even custom-apps or contacts.

How would one mimick such a behavior?

Comment: Oh, btw, the Widgetsoid-app works also on Android 1.6 and up (1.6 has a separate version, the others are designed for 2.x, but also work flawlessly on Honeycomb on my tablet)... I am using it frequently on Milestone2 and Acer Iconia A500 with 3.2.1.
So apparently, there is a way.

Comment: This page here indicates how Widgetsoid does it, by pressing a toggle-button, a small popup is opened that does the toggle-function and then disappears again: http://jaumard.android.free.fr/widgetsoid/help_widgetsoid.php?lang=en_EN